# Sqlite column doesn't exist

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

This is my problem; I'm creating tables from asset all are in one file and rest of the tables doesn't create any problem.

This one table is reporting:

> 04-29 22:13:09.434: E/SQLiteDatabase(6378):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table gym_exercise has no
>   column named date: , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   gym_exercise(cals,date) VALUES (?,?)

and this is the create statement

```
create table gym_training (_id integer primary key autoincrement, cals integer not null, date text not null);
```

I tried renaming this column, tried not inserting value for that column and then I'm getting constraint error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the table names mixed up. You probably want to insert into **`gym_training`**, not `gym_exercise`.

Comment: i tryed couple of times must wait one minute

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps date has special meaning in SQLite, too (it does in other databases). Try changing the name to something else. You'll need to update all your references if this field is referenced from other tables (I think you can do that in SQlite, although the references aren't enforced)

Comment: nope other tables have that column too that was the first thing i thought of